# error TS4081: Exported type alias 'TemplateLiteralType' has or is using private name ''. Along with error TS1110: Type expected

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with Template Literal Types, and running into 2 TypeScript compiler errors which I can't find anything about online.

I've constructed a tiny example (not quite minimal, the error comes even without the intermediary type YesNo):

src/temp.ts:

```
export const yes_no = ["yes", "no"] as const

export type YesNo = (typeof yes_no)[number]

export type TemplateLiteralType = `Does this work ${YesNo}`
```

From everything I know about TemplateLiteralTypes, this should work. I think the code even used to work.
But tsc is giving me the following errors:

```
src/temp.ts:5:34 - error TS4081: Exported type alias 
'TemplateLiteralType' has or is using private name ''.

5 export type TemplateLiteralType = `Does this work ${YesNo}`
  

src/temp.ts:5:35 - error TS1110: Type expected.

5 export type TemplateLiteralType = `Does this work ${YesNo}`
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note the empty string in `(...) private name ''.`
Have the rules for Template Literal Types changed? Am I seeing a tsc compiler bug? Or what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, it might really have been a tsc bug. Updating typescript (`npm i -g typescript`) made `tsc` run without hickups.